# Cortar en varias partes cadena de caracteres C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, filesystem

Buenas noches.

Como puedo convertir la siguiete cadena: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,application/pdf"  en lo siguiente: ".jpg,.pdf,.zip"

Tomando en cuenta tambien que la primera cadena puede incluir mas extensiones.

Gracias.

Comment: Comparte lo que has intentado por favor.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que en la cadena original no existe `zip` por ningun lado, no creo que sea posible transformarlo en ".jpg,.pdf,.zip". Bromas aparte, hay muchisimas formas de hacerlo, asi que debes mostrarnos que has intentado y porque no ha funcionado.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar expresiones regulares:

```
    var cadena = "image/jpg,image/jpeg,application/pdf";
    // Obtenemos las extensiones
    var result = Regex.Matches(cadena, @"\w+/(\w+)")
        .Cast<Match>().Select(x => $".{x.Groups[1].Value}");
    // Concatena las extensiones utilizando la , como separador
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
```